# Clarification for range of function of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ have the pdf $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$

Find the pdf of $Y=|X|$

I know that this can be done by find the cdf of $Y$:

$\Pr[Y \le y]$

I don't need help finding the pdf, but it's mentioned in my notes that if $y<0$ then the cdf of $Y$ is $F_{Y}(y)=0$

Can someone please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y<0$, $F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(|X|\leq y)$. The latter number is the probability that |X| is smaller than a negative number (here y), which obviously zero because $|X|$ is almost surely positive.

Answer (score 1):

Because the absolute value can never be negative. In other words, the absolute value "folds" the negative part of your pdf over the positive part, doubling it, leaving the negative part zero.